# HTMLPurifier, check entire HTML document

Tags: php, html, htmlpurifier

I'm using HTMLPurifier to check for XSS in an entire HTML document. The problem is that it appears to strip out anyything that isn’t inside `<body>` tags. But, I want to keep everything, just look out for serious XSS attacks.

Any ideas how to allow `<HTML>`, `<HEAD>`, `<META>` etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

David, I just searched on the HTMLPurifier support forum and saw that you've been busy.

But perhaps you missed the posting from a few months ago that [addresses your exact issue](http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?5,3711,3711#msg-3711), specifically the reply:

> Full document support will
>   (ostensibly) come some time in the
>   HTML Purifier 5.x series; we don't
>   actually have the parsing code
>   necessary to actually deal with full
>   HTML documents.

Until then, you'll want to capture your head and DTD and re-add it to the purified doc.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you can construct an XSS attack that runs from 'head'.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell HTML Purifier what tag the purified code will be inside (it defaults to 'div'). Setting this to 'span' would block all block-level tags. You could experiment with setting it to 'body', or even to 'html'.